Diff-in-diff with balanced panel: adding fixed effects does not change coefficients?
I'm trying to run a differences-in-differences model in Stata. My dependent variable is order volumes, each observation is 1 store, and my panel is strongly balanced (20 quarters for each store, 6K control stores, 4K treated stores). I am running the following regression:
reghdfe orders treat post treat_post, noabsorb cluster(chain)
If I then add fixed effects (time-, individual-, or anything else), my coefficients on treat, post, and treat_post do not change at all. E.g., the following regressions all give identical coefficients with identical standard errors:
reghdfe orders treat treat_post, absorb(date) cluster(chain)
reghdfe orders post treat_post, absorb(store_id_number) cluster(chain)
reghdfe orders treat_post, absorb(date store_id_number) cluster(chain)
In my understanding, the coefficient on treat_post should change each time, since I am including different fixed effects? What  am I doing wrong, and what could be going on?

This is either HW or cross-posted with an answer.
